# Angular 5 Router with Lazy Loading Modules not working

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an app and I make the structure to have feature modules with owns routes:

// Here is the Feature Module

```
RouterModule.forChild([
    {
        path: ':cube_id/import-data',
        component: ImportDataComponent,
        canActivate: [CUBE_GUARD]
    },
    {
        path: ':cube_id/consolidation',
        component: ConsolidationComponent,
        canActivate: [CUBE_GUARD]
    }
     ....
```

// App routing:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

    {
        path: 'epic',
        loadChildren: './traitement/traitement.module#TraitementModule'
    },
    { 
        path: 'not-authorized', 
        component: NotAuthorizedComponent 
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full',
        canActivate: [ HOME_GUARD ],
        children: [

        ]
    }
];


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { 
            useHash: true
        })
    ],
    providers: [
        CurrentUserService,
        GuardFactory.createGuard(HOME_GUARD, homeGuard)
    ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

And in root app module I have imported the AppRoutingModule.

When I try to access the item from menu, I get this error:

```
core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'epic/import-data'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'epic/import-data'
```

**If I import Features Modules in Root Module everything works fine.**
 Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: isn't path declared in route is `epic/<cube_id>/import-data`?

Answer (score 3):

As per your configuration, routing is expecting dynamic value `:cube_id`. So basically your path should be as -

```
epic/1/import-data
```

Check your `routerLink` and pass the value for cube_id.

ex :

```
<a [routerLink]="['/epic', id, 'import-data']">Home</a>
```

Comment: I have a Cube, so it's 3 drop down items in menu with same sub items so we use same component for 3 different menu items. And it's set like this: 
<a [routerLink]= "['epic', 'consolidation']" id="c_epic">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 
              {{ 'MENU.epic.consolidation' | translate }}
            </a><a [routerLink]= "['prev', 'consolidation']" id="c_epic">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 
              {{ 'MENU.epic.consolidation' | translate }}
            </a>

Comment: yeah, here you are not passing `cube_id` however as per your configuration it is mendatory.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "cube_id" after /epic as your route configuration contains id. So your URL will become epic/{{id}}/import-data. If you don't want to pass any id, just create another route without id.If you want to handle such errors related to routing just add this code to app-routing.module.ts file.

```
export class AppRoutingModule{ 
  constructor(private router : Router){
    this.router.errorHandler = (error: any) =>{
      showSomeErrorPage();`enter code here`
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sunil Singh and Pooja Pawar I solve it adding this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

    {
        path: ':cube_id',
        loadChildren: './traitement/traitement.module#TraitementModule'
    },
```

And in view:

```
  <li routerLinkActive="current-item" *requiresAuthorization="['prof', 'journal']">
    <a [routerLink]="['prof', 'prof', 'journal']" id="j_prof">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 
      {{ 'MENU.prof.journal' | translate }}
    </a>
  </li>
```